# In the DWARF info, what do they exactly mean by the DW_OP registers?

Tags: c++, c, debugging, stack, dwarf

I am trying to parse the `DWARF` info and then using that information get the local variables from a program using a pin tool. It is kind of like using `pin` as `GDB` on steroids. However, I am having troubles understanding what they mean by the registers they have for the local variables and allocated ones.

For example,

```
<2>< 1214>  DW_TAG_variable
    DW_AT_name                  mts
    DW_AT_decl_line             69
    DW_AT_type                  <90>
    DW_AT_location              DW_OP_breg4+44
```

I understand that, in order to get the data from the variable mts, I have to add 44 to some register, my problem is that I don't exactly which register they are talking about. How should I interpret this? I couldn't find anything online.

Another examples are the `DW_OP_fbreg`, `DW_OP_breg5` and so on.

Anyone knows which registers are they talking about in an `x86` context? Are they talking about ebp or esp? Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

It's a symbolic register name.  See the `xxx_map_dwarf_register` methods in [WineHQ](http://www.winehq.org/)'s source for:

- [i386](http://source.winehq.org/source/dlls/dbghelp/cpu_i386.c#L517)
- [x86_64](http://source.winehq.org/source/dlls/dbghelp/cpu_x86_64.c#L739)
- [sparc](http://source.winehq.org/source/dlls/dbghelp/cpu_sparc.c#L55)
- [arm](http://source.winehq.org/source/dlls/dbghelp/cpu_arm.c#L160)

For example, `DW_OP_breg4` is `ESP` on i386.

Also see the following if you haven't done so already.

- http://source.winehq.org/source/dlls/dbghelp/dwarf.c
- http://www.dwarfstd.org/doc/040408.1.html

Comment: Yeah, that's telling you it's stored at the address in esp plus 44.  The DWARF spec can be found at http://www.dwarfstd.org/ - that's usually the best reference, although it won't have architecture/ABI-specific information like how DWARF register numbers map to i386 register names.